# optimize.root with a matrix equation

Tags: numpy, matrix, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve the following linear system using optimize.root

```
AX = b
```

With the following code.

```
A = [[0,1,0],[2,1,0],[1,4,1]]

def foo(X):
   b = np.matrix([2,1,1])
   out = np.dot(A,X) - b
   return out.tolist()

sol = scipy.optimize.root(foo,[0,0,0])
```

I know that I can simply use the `numpy.linalg.solve` to do this easily. But I am actually trying to solve a non linear system that is in matrix form. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050268/solving-a-sparse-non-linear-system-of-equations-using-scipy-optimize-root). So I need to find a way to make this method work. To do that I am trying to solve this problem in this simple case. But I get the error

```
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'foo'.Shape should be (3,) but it is (1, 3).
```

From what I have read from other similar stackoverflow questions this happens because the out put of the foo function is not compatible with the shape of the initial guess `[0,0,0]`

Surely there is a way to solve this equation using scipy.optimize.root. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming the capital `B` in your `.dot` is a typo for `A`.)

Try using `np.array` for `b`. `np.matrix` creates a "row vector", i.e. shape `(1, 3)` whereas your initial guess has shape `(3,)`.

Comment: Sorry. Yes it is a typo for `A`.

Comment: How do I transform the output of the function `foo` to the shape `(3,)`?

Comment: Doesn't using `np.array` for `b` work? And I'm pretty sure you don't need the `.tolist()`.

Comment: No you still get the same error unfortunately. I tried transposing the matrices. But Still doesn't work. I used `b = np.array([2,1,1])`

Comment: Strange, works fpr me. Is your posted code identical to the one you're actually using? I'm asking because if for example you were using an `np.matrix` for `A` instead of a list of lists it wouldn't work.

Comment: You are right it works. I tried this on a new jupyternotebook and it works. I think some function got overwriten with something I had declared earlier. I wonder if this has been happening every time. Thanks for the help.